# Excel diff with python

Tags: python, excel, diff

I am looking for an algorithm to comapre two excel sheets, based on their column names, in Python.

I do not know what the columns are, so one sheet may have an additional column or both sheets can have several columns with the same name.

The easiest case is when a column in the first sheet corresponds to only one column in the second excel sheet. Then I can perform the diff on rows of that column using `xlrd`.
If the column name is not unique, I can verify if the columns have the same position.

Does anyone know of an already existing algorithm or have any experience in this domain?

Comment: I've done quite a lot of work on Excel sheets in my days.. There's no real algorithm for this kind of task but it depends on what your result should look like.. ignore non matching column names or combine them into a joint list?

Comment: Actually I want to highlight non-matching cells of matching columns and highlight the whole non-matching columns. I mean the columns that are missing or are additional in the second sheet. What is the use of combining the non matching column names into a joint list?

Comment: So, **1:** Show matching colum names, **2:** Highlight NON matching values within those two columns?

Comment: yes, and add the column names which are missing in the second sheet where they appear in the first sheet as well.But actually I am not sure if I am capturing all matching columns like this. When the column name is not unique, it would not be that easy.

Comment: Posted a two-row solution to your problem, which, assumes you've already got the `xlrd` rowdata and names. Let me know if you need help with `xlrd` specifics such as getting row values :)

Comment: Could you give an example on the sheet data? For instance, are the colum names repeating? like so: `Animals     Colors     Animals     Colortype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast an dirty:

```
# Since order of the names doesn't matter, we can use the set() option
matching_names = set(sheet_one_names) & set(sheet_one_names)
...
# Here, order does matter since we're comparing rowdata..
# not just if they match at some point.
matching_rowdata = [i for i, j in zip(columndata_one, columndata_two) if i != j]
```

Note: This assumes that you've done a few things ahead,

1. get the column names for sheet 1 via `xlrd` and same for the second sheet,
2. get the row data for both sheets in two different variables.

This is to give you an idea.

Also note that doing the [...] option (second one) it's important that the rows are of the same length, otherwise it will be skipped. This is a **MISS-MATCH** scenario, reverse to get the matches in the data flow.

This is a slower but functional solution:

```
column_a_name = ['Location', 'Building', 'Location']
column_a_data = [['Floor 1', 'Main', 'Sweden'],
                ['Floor 2', 'Main', 'Sweden'],
                ['Floor 3', 'Main', 'Sweden']]

column_b_name = ['Location', 'Building']
column_b_data = [['Sweden', 'Main', 'Floor 1'],
                ['Norway', 'Main', 'Floor 2'],
                ['Sweden', 'Main', 'Floor 3']]

matching_names = []
for pos in range(0, len(column_a_name)):
    try:
        if column_a_name[pos] == column_b_name[pos]:
            matching_names.append((column_a_name[pos], pos))
    except:
        pass # Index out of range, column length are not the same

mismatching_data = []
for row in range(0, len(column_a_data)):
    rowa = column_a_data[row]
    rowb = column_b_data[row]

    for name, _id in matching_names:
        if rowa[_id] != rowb[_id] and (rowa[_id] not in rowb or rowb[_id] not in rowa):
            mismatching_data.append((row, rowa[_id], rowb[_id]))

print mismatching_data
```

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if a name appears twice in both sheets, what would be the criteria to find the matching columns? I mean when there is no one-to-one relation between column names in both sheets?

Comment: Check if this works to your liking. i get `[(1, 'Sweden', 'Norway')]` as a missmatch, which, should be what you're looking for? Note that 1 is the row that the failure hit on, and i count on column_a being the largest (that's something you'll have to add fail safe for by checking which column is the longest etc etc)

Comment: Thanks, yes this is one of the cases. Another could have been that the second location would match with the Location in column_b_name. Or that the position of the matching names was not matching at all. I suppose there is no algorithm doing such a thing. It can get really complicated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added a fix for that.
Now it matches if the row is different and the values are not mixed up. According to your second scenario.. This way you cover both of those :)

Comment: I've looked at a similar problem on my old work, i added translation tables for known irregulareties in the column names, then i added fuzzy logic matching strings within the cells giving me some rough estimates on what was missmatching even if the in-data was miss-spelled or placed in the wrong cells.
And at some points i skipped the cell-names and just matched the row data matched against ALL other rowdata just to see if the rows were missplaced/wrong order, ergo, if 1 cell existed at all in the other cells in the other document and then if THAT row matched the one where the cell originated.